# Javascript create element issue

Tags: javascript, performance, createelement

When i create the object like on the example A, it won't apply any attribute (id,class,etc...).
The element is being created but without attributes. Option B works fine, but according to this [Spped tests](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-createelement/56) its 25% slower. How to apply attributes using option A? Is it possible after all? Thanks for all smart answers!

A:

```
  var page = $(document.createElement("div"), {
         "id": "projects",
         "class": "page activePage"
    });
```

B:

```
var page = document.createElement("div"); 
page.id = 'projects'; 
page.className = 'page activePage';
```

Comment: Please indicate what Javascript framework you are using `$` is not native javascript.  I am guessing jQuery, but you should be specific.  You should not expect a framework, which adds abstraction layers, checks against browser variation, and so forth to have the same performance as raw native DOM manipulation.   The real question is, why do you need to optimize?  Remember, the first rule of optimization is:  don't optimize.

Comment: I am using jquery and i am making a single page website completely powered by javascript/jquery/json. So i dynamically build dom using javascript and i think its really important to choose the fastest option and to reduce the loading time of each page to a minimum. Don't you think the same?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ The `$` object exists natively in modern browsers. It selects an element by ID.

Comment: Actually, no I don't think that at all.  Processor cycles are one of the cheapest resources we have in 2012. It is not 1958 where every byte and cycle is precious.   What I teach the developers on my staff is to optimize for developer time, especially maintainability.  Make it clear, effective, and easy to maintain.  Only if there is performance problem--which there almost never is--should one go back and optimize which nearly always make the code harder to understand,  and harder to manage changes in business rules over time.

Comment: @JanDvorak If that is true--and I never read anything about it--it is a crazy design decision in a world where so many frameworks hijack that name.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ, I'd never heard about that either, but I just opened up a blank tab in the latest version of Chrome and entered `$` into the console. Lo and behold I get this back: `function () { [native code] }`

Comment: @BenLee Wow -- you learn something new every day.  Still, I will never use it, since I cannot imagine developing without a framework for anything more than a trivial test page.  I have used Dojo these past few years, but am seriously unhappy with its design direction and thinking of switching to jQuery.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ present in Chrome and Firefox. Firefox delegates to getElementById, Chrome mumbles something about native code.

Comment: And it's not just ids. For example, going to 'asdf.com' and typing `$('a')` into the console indeed returns the first anchor tag (confirmed that no `$` framework was defined there).

Comment: @BenLee $ is implemented in firefox as `(function JSTH_$(aId) {"use strict";return aJSTerm.window.document.getElementById(aId);})`

Comment: @JanDvorak You haven't mentioned the elephant in the room.  For example, my company just barely finished switching to IE 7 (despite my screams, as head of the web development team--health care is very retro).

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ MY company decided we don't have the time to support IE7 and we barely support IE8

Comment: OK, IE9 >>> $ returns a reference error.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: `$` is only available in the console and not on the page (on Chrome at least). There are other convenience functions available there, like `clear()`.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Firefox says `ReferenceError: '$' is not defined`. As others have mentioned, this is a feature of the firefox console, not firefox the browser.

Comment: I think the lesson is always type code into a blank HTML file to test it. Don't trust the browser console too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option doesn't make any sense; that's not how jQuery works (assuming you are using jQuery because of the `$()` construction). In jQuery, you'd do it like this:

```
var page = $('<div>').attr('id', 'projects').addClass('page').addClass('activePage');
```

There are other ways to accomplish this via jQuery, but any way you do it would even be slower than option B above, since it's basically doing the same thing as option B behind the scenes, with a lot of framework around it to slow it down.

Even if the `$` refers to a different framework, the same applies -- it can't be faster than the built-in javascript methods.

Even more importantly: The speed here is most likely not significant at all. Does this get run thousands of times? If not, no need to care about speed here. And in the rare case it's significant, you're not going to get any faster than option B, using just vanilla javascript.

Comment: Don't you create DOM elements with `$('<div>')`?

Comment: @phant0m, typo on my part. Fixed.

Comment: So the option B is the best and fastest available option, no?

Comment: @hjuster, yes, it is no doubt the fastest. No way to make it faster. Best? That's up for debate. I'd say using jQuery is the best, but that's a matter of opinion. Use whatever method is clearest to read and easiest to maintain.

Comment: Ben thanks for all ur comments/answers. Man of your reputation must be right! :) Anyway...finally i'll go for the option B , maybe its not clearer to read, but its fastest as you said.

Comment: This is almost right. Change $('<div'>)  --> $('<div/>') to create a new node

Answer (score 0):

So, Why not directly use this ?

**EDIT:**

```
var page = '<div id:"projects" class:"page activePage"></div>'
var page = '<div id="projects" class="page activePage"></div>'
```

OR

```
document.createElement("div",{id:"projects",class:"page activePage"});
```

I suggest first if you are creating static data.

Hope, It will helps you. Thanks. !!

Comment: @hjuster: see my edited answer. I first answered jQuery just because you have mentioned `jQuery` in you tags and not clarified about framework and usage.

Comment: It's ok. If this answer help you than please mark this as answer.

Comment: This doesn't help me... it gives this error INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5

Comment: @hjuster: see my edited answer. i have tested in firebug and it will works fine for me.

Comment: The second example doesn't apply the id, neither the class. And the first example is far slower than my option B.

Answer (score -1):

We can able to create the div element using the jquery and it won't cause any performance issue since it is not based on javascript

```
1. $("<div class='page activePage' id ='projects'></div>")

2. $('<div>').attr('id', 'projects').addClass('page').addClass('activePage');
```

Thanks

Comment: What? jQuery is most definitely based on javascript.

Comment: jquery is not based on javascript ?! Are you kidding me?

Comment: hi guys sorry you misunderstood i mean that directly using javascript will cause some performance issue whereas using jquery won't. We have moved to jquery because of performance and the browser compatibility.

Comment: In the terms of performance javascript is far better then jquery. Jquery is used because it has a lot of integrated methods and its easier to use. ,,Write less, do more" ...

Comment: @SridharNarasimhan, no we didn't misunderstand you. You simply have it totally backwards. *jQuery is built on top of javascript*. Any well-written plain javascript will be *at least as fast* as the equivalent functionality built into jQuery, almost by definition. You're right that jQuery is good for browser compatibility, for simplicity, for avoiding errors in common tasks, etc... But efficiency vs. plain javascript is definitely not a reason to use it.